# RecyclerView doesn't update UI with data from database

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-room

My db is being populated and being used to create a viewModel. When debugging it seems like everything is working as intended, but when i run the code i get an emoty recyclerView

My methods fetching MovieItems from the db

```
 public Single<List<MovieListItem>> getFavoriteslist(Context context) {
    return Single.fromCallable(() -> getFavoritesFromDb(context))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}

 private List<MovieListItem> getFavoritesFromDb(Context context) {
    List<Movie> favoriteMovies = Database.getAppDatabase(context).movieDao().getAll();
    List<MovieListItem> favoriteList = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < favoriteMovies.size(); i++) {
        MovieListItem favoriteListItem = new MovieListItem();
        Movie movieObject = favoriteMovies.get(i);

        favoriteListItem.setId(movieObject.getMovieId());
        favoriteListItem.setImageUrl(movieObject.getPosterPath());
        favoriteListItem.setTitle(movieObject.getMovieName());
        favoriteListItem.setVoteCount(movieObject.getVoteCount());
        favoriteListItem.setVoteAverage(movieObject.getVoteAverage());
        favoriteListItem.setVotePopularity(movieObject.getPopularity());
        favoriteListItem.setOverview(movieObject.getOverview());
        favoriteListItem.setReleaseDate(movieObject.getReleaseDate());
        favoriteList.add(favoriteListItem);
    }
    return favoriteList;
}
```

heres the method that replaces old data in the recycler view with the new data:

```
         if (id == R.id.action_favorite) {
        mCurrentSort = SORT_FAVORITE;
        mCompositDisposable.clear();
        mCompositDisposable.add(movieGridViewModel.getFavoriteslist(getContext()).subscribe(movieListItems ->
        {
            if (mMovieGridAdapter != null) {
                mMovieGridAdapter.clearAllMovieData();
                mMovieGridAdapter.loadFavoriteMovies(movieListItems);
                mMovieGridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                mMovieGridAdapter = new MovieGridAdapter(getActivity(), movieListItems);
                mMovieGridAdapter.setClickListener(this);
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mMovieGridAdapter);
                mMovieGridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }, throwable -> {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "no internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }));
    }
```

It appears that the adapter has the data but for some reason the UI is not being updated.

Comment: Did you try do `Log` your `getFavoritesFromDb` is it empty or you have data inside?

Comment: You need to set the layout manager on the recyclerview